# Unity - Infinite sprite spawner stops spawning at a high speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

i wrote a script for my 2D car game for an infinite track. So i got a "killer" behind my car, that destroys all ground objects coming out the screen on the left and on the right i have a spawner that spawns all my blocky sprites in it and it works pretty good.
Here is my update function:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) == limit)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Limit reached");
        limit += 10;
        Spawn();
    }
}
```

I attached the script to my camera and i have a start limit set to 160 (because i already got 15 10x10 sprites as start). Everytime my spawner passes the x-axis-limit it spawns a new sprite at this position and sets the next limit 10 higher. This works good if I don't drive too fast. Because then it stops spawning and the world is cut off. When I drive back to get my spawner back into the already spawned area and drive slowly again to it, it works again. I believe the method is just to inefficient to spawn fast enough so I maybe need another style of doing it.

For the understanding here the rest of the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] obj;
    private int limit = 160;
    public int yAxisValue = -1;
    public bool isOnlyDirt;
    private ArrayList rotationValues = new ArrayList();


void Start()
{
    //Spawn ();
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        rotationValues.Add(value);
        //Debug.Log(rotationValues[i]);
        value += 90;
    }
}

void Spawn()
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (Mathf.Round(transform.position.x), yAxisValue, transform.position.z);

    Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 0, 0);
    if(isOnlyDirt)
    {
        int zRot = (int)rotationValues[Random.Range(0, rotationValues.Count - 1)];
        //Debug.Log(zRot);
        rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, zRot, 0);
    }

    var SpawnedGround = Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], pos, rotation);

    (SpawnedGround as GameObject).gameObject.tag = "Gro
```

I also have a one-liner to move my spawner in front of my car so it can spawn things:

```
public float yCoord;


void Start ()
{
    this.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + 160, -yCoord, transform.position.z);
}
```

I parented it so i just have to write it in the start function.

Any ideas to improve this one?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry can't post as comments. You should try

```
if(Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) >= limit)
```

instead of

```
if(Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) == limit)
```

I think the floating point precision is skipping the checking.

Comment: Oh thanks that is a quite good idea ^^ that didn't fixed it completely so i had some ugly holes left but i came up with the idea to just replace the Mathf.Round in the Instanciation-method with just the limit and this works now.

Comment: You could also try pooling your track sprite objects and changing their position instead... This would save having to instantiate and destroy the same objects all of the time